# Get display number for a given tty

Tags: x11, tty

How can I find out if X is running on a given TTY on a Debian machine and in that case retrieve the display number (value of DISPLAY)?

Edit: The TTY may be an inactive console, not necessarily the active one. I'm trying to implement the function

```
Display()
{
    local tty="$1"
    ...
}
```

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` ?

Comment: @schaiba I'm trying to implement the function tty -> displaynr for any tty, not just the active one.

Comment: What OS will this be run on? Can we assume Linux?

Comment: @terdon I use Debian 9. Can't we always assume that questions in this forum are related to Unix-like operating systems?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom i) no, sadly. You'd be surprised at how often we get people running completely different systems. ii) more importantly, Unix, BSD, OSX, Linux, and all other Unix and Unix-like systems are on topic here and each behaves slightly differently. My answer below, for example, will only work on Linux (or any other system that uses `/proc`, but many Unix-like systems do not).

Answer (score 5):

You could search by process name. And then look at the unix domain sockets (possibly abstract) open by the process to determine the display number.

```
pid=$(pgrep -xt "$tty" Xorg) &&
  lsof -aUp "$pid" | sed '\|.*X11-unix/X\([0-9]\{1,\}\) .*|!d;s//\1/;q'
```

That `lsof` would have to run as root.

Or you could extract the display number from the command line arguments if it's always there:

```
pgrep -axt "$tty" Xorg | sed -n 's/.*:\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of an easy way to solve the mapping of `/dev/ttyNN` to `$DISPLAY`. However, it is possible. On my Debian based system this will return the local `DISPLAY` value `:0` for an X session running on `/dev/tty7`:

```
xtty=/dev/tty7
xpid=$(lsof "$xtty" 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 == "Xorg" {print $2}')
test -n "$xpid" && ps -fp "$xpid" | awk '$2 == xpid {print $9}' xpid="$xpid"    # → :0
```

The intermediate stages are as follows.

1. The `lsof` returns all processes open on the given tty terminal. The `awk` picks out the process id for the process named `Xorg`. YMMV if you're not running that particular X display server.

   ```
   lsof /dev/tty7 2>/dev/null
   COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   Xorg    695 root    8u   CHR    4,7      0t0 1059 /dev/tty7
   ```
2. The `ps | awk` combination provides sufficient details of the matched `Xorg` process to deliver the `DISPLAY` name:

   ```
   ps -fp 695
   UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
   root       695   639  0 Jan23 tty7     00:01:44 /usr/bin/X :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm
   ```

Comment: I have no Xorg command in the output from lsof. The first three commands are startx, xinit, and blackbox.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom does `ps -ef` give you any process name that contains something like the `:0` I show in my breakdown step 2?

Comment: Yes, step two works.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom what's the process name that includes the `DISPLAY` value, and which field number on that process line contains the value?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a Linux machine and GNU tools, this should work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Get Xorg's tty
xorgTTY="$(ps -o tty= "$(pgrep Xorg)")"
## Get the DISPLAY from a process running on that tty
while read pid; do
    display="$(grep -aoP 'DISPLAY=\K[^\0]+' /proc/"$pid"/environ)" && break
done < <(pgrep -t "$xorgTTY")
echo "$display"
```

Comment: Very nice way of handling the null terminator in environ. I'll have to put that in my bag of tricks.

Comment: I don't think there's a GNU implementation of `ps` or `pgrep`.

Comment: I get a question mark as the output from the ps command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas no, but I am using GNU extensions of `grep` (`-P` and, I think, `-o` are both GNU).

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom are you running this on a Linux machine that is currently running Xorg?

Comment: @terdon Yes, I have exactly one X session running on tty1. Also I don't use a display manager.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom then that's strange. Does `pgrep Xorg` return a PID?

Comment: @terdon Yes, `pgrep Xorg` returns a PID. For me, your entire script only outputs a blank line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54505/discussion-between-terdon-and-august-karlstrom).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work, assuming `bash` is the shell.

```
TTY="pts/20"
BASH_PID="$(ps -t $TTY|awk '$4 == "bash" {print $1;exit}')"
TTY_DISPLAY=$(tr '\000' '\n' < /proc/$BASH_PID/environ|awk -F'=' '$1 == "DISPLAY" {print $2}')
```

We're specifying a TTY, grabbing the first bash pid we find and then extracting the `DISPLAY` var from `/proc/pid/environ`.

Answer (score 1):

On a machine using systemd-logind (which should include Debian 8), you can query logind as follows:

```
DisplayName()
{
  local ttynr="$1"
  declare -A property
  for session in $(loginctl --no-legend list-sessions | awk '{ print $1 }' ); do
    while IFS="=" read key value ; do
      property[$key]="$value"
    done < <(loginctl show-session $session)

    if [ "${property[VTNr]}" = "$ttynr" ] && [ -n "${property[Display]}" ]; then
      echo "${property[Display]}"
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Using your method with loginctl is more stable then the solution I suggested which uses the output of `ps -ef`.

Answer (score 0):

On my Debian 8 system, all X processes receive the virtual terminal (e.g. `vt1`) and display name (e.g. `:0`) as arguments. However, depending on if an X session was started by a display manager or from the console, the position of the arguments differ. Inspired by roaima's answer I wrote the following shell function:

```sh
DisplayName()
{
    local ttyNr="$1"

    ps -ef | awk -v ttyNr="$ttyNr" \
        '$8 == "/usr/bin/X" {
            for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) {
                if ($i == "vt" ttyNr) {
                    isMatch = 1
                } else if ($i ~ "^:[0-9]+$") {
                    display = $i
                }
            }
            if (isMatch) {
                print display
                exit
            }
        }'
}
```

Comment: @roaima This site says I have to wait two days to do that.

Comment: ah ok didn't realise that

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the shortest answer could be one single letter:

```
$ w

USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
arnie97  tty1     -                21:50    2:11   9.94s  8.88s -bash
arnie97  tty7     :0               20:56    1:09m 45.68s  0.02s /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
arnie97  pts/0    192.168.0.1      22:31    0.00s  0.44s  0.30s vi
```

As for scripting:

```
$ w -h | awk '$3 ~ /^:/ { if ($2 == "tty7") print $3 }'

:0
```